Hear Japanese words and phrases, practice writing the corresponding kana
I'm looking for a website that will play Japanese words and phrases aloud, and then check my accuracy in hand-writing (on my phone) the kana for whatever was played aloud.
Though I can do this myself by generating random strings of kana, having the phone read them aloud, and then checking my hand-written forms with the original, I'd prefer something more professional-looking. I'm not looking for vocabulary practice, just a way to build up speed in writing the kana accurately without copying by eye.
Any ideas?
